# Why does C++20's requires expression not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-traits, requires-expression

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct IsComplete final
    : std::bool_constant<requires{sizeof(T);}>
{};

int main()
{
    struct A;
    static_assert(!IsComplete<A>::value); // ok

    struct A{};
    static_assert(IsComplete<A>::value);  // error
}
```

I expected that the second `static_assert` should be true as A is a complete type now.

**Why does C++20's requires expression not behave as expected?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a wrong expectation. To start with, a class template has only one point of instantiation in a translation unit:

> **[temp.point]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep.res#temp.point-7) ... A specialization for a class template has at most one point of
> instantiation within a translation unit. A specialization for any
> template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation
> units. If two different points of instantiation give a template
> specialization different meanings according to the one-definition
> rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Templates never allowed for two points in the program to have a different interpretation of the template for the same set of arguments (an ODR nightmare in the general case). You basically start venturing into nasal-demon territory with your attempt at the trait.

And should you think using C++20 concepts is gonna change anything, you'll dive right into ill-formed; no diagnostic required territory if you conceptify the example

```
template<typename T>
concept IsComplete = requires{sizeof(T);};

int main()
{
    struct A;
    static_assert(!IsComplete<A>); // ok

    struct A{};
    static_assert(IsComplete<A>);  // error or nuclear launch.
}
```

> **[temp.names]**
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp#names-8.sentence-3) ... A concept-id evaluates to true if the concept's normalized
> constraint-expression is satisfied ([temp.constr.constr]) by the
> specified template arguments and false otherwise.
>
> **[temp.constr.atomic]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp#constr.atomic-3.sentence-5) ... If, at different points in the program, the satisfaction
> result is different for identical atomic constraints and template
> arguments, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

It's not anything new, concepts just add more of the same. A template's meaning for a specific set of arguments must not change if some property of the arguments is different in two different points in the program.

So while a concept (even in pre-C++20 SFINAE hackery) that checks if a type is complete *may* be written, to use it carelessly is to play with fire.

Comment: This can even be seen in action: https://cppinsights.io/s/67df151f Only 1 new `struct` is created for `A` and is used in both cases.

Comment: You can even "fix" it by adding a dummy, unique parameter to the template, e.g. `template<typename T, int _line>` and `IsComplete<A, __LINE__>`

Comment: If the two declarations of `struct A` are declared in different blocks we get two different types and both assertions pass: https://cppinsights.io/s/f7e69e33

Comment: In this case, @md2perpe, that's because each `struct A` defines a distinct type, and thus `IsComplete` will be [instantiated twice](https://godbolt.org/z/KjrcPPdde).

Comment: @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica. I know. That's what I wanted to show.